# How do I get the IndexSet of a ForEach method without using :perform

Tags: swift, swiftui

This was my original method for deleting items in a list using swipe to delete.

```
@AppStorage("arrayOfItems") var arrayOfItems: [String] = []

if(arrayOfItems.count > 0) {
  ForEach((0..<arrayOfItems.count), id: \.self) {
      Text(arrayOfItems[$0])
      }
      .onDelete(perform: deleteSelectedItems) }

func deleteSelectedItems(with indexSet: IndexSet) {
    indexSet.forEach ({ index in
        arrayOfItems.remove(at: index)
    })
}
```

However, now I am using `.swipeactions` with IOS15 which disables the `onDelete` method so I am unsure of what arguments to inside into the `deleteSelectedItems` function.

```
@AppStorage("arrayOfItems") var arrayOfItems: [String] = []

        if(arrayOfItems.count > 0) {
      ForEach((0..<arrayOfItems.count), id: \.self) {
          Text(arrayOfItems[$0])
          }
          .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
             Button(role: .destructive) {
               deleteSelectedItems(with: IndexSet???????????)} label: {
               Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                      }
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this `ForEach((0..<arrayOfItems.count), id: \.self) { index in }`. `index` is **index** of the row you tap.

#### iOS 15+

```
ForEach((0..<arrayOfItems.count), id: \.self) { index in  // NEW
    Text(arrayOfItems[index])
      .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
            Button(role: .destructive) {
              deleteSelectedItems(index)} label: {
                  Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
            }
       }
}
```

#### iOS 14

```
 ForEach((0..<arrayOfItems.count), id: \.self) {
     Text(arrayOfItems[$0])
 }
 .onDelete { indexset in 
    indexSet.forEach ({ index in
        deleteSelectedItems(index)
    })
  }
```

Change `deleteSelectedItems` to this

```
func deleteSelectedItems(with index: Int) {
    arrayOfItems.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for replying. This does not work as my deleteSelectedItems requires an IndexSet and not an Int. When I use deleteSelectedItems, I have to give an argument like deleteSelectedItems(with: "IndexSetorWtvData")

Comment: It is not done that way. `arrayOfItems` should a `RandomAccessCollection`, preferably an array of `Identifible` elements. Could you include `arrayOfItems` too. @throwawayaccount123

Comment: Should I be changing my deleteSelectedItems method? I just edited it in! Thank you

Comment: `arrayOfItems` is one dimensional. Why do you need indexset? @throwawayaccount123

Comment: This is because I was previously using the method together with the onDelete method providing by the List which automatically helped me to sync and use them together as the onDelete (perform:) gives an IndexSet as well.

Comment: You need to refactor your code. Check the update @throwawayaccount123

Comment: Unfortunately the index in ForEach cannot be found in scope of .swipeactions

Comment: @throwawayaccount123 Had used it incorrectly. Have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the struct `Hashable` and `Identifiable`, you can perform delete action like this:

eg:

```
struct A:Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var num: Int
}

    List {
        ForEach(arrItems, id: \.self) { (item) in
            Text("Item Number \(item.num)")
                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                    Button(role: .destructive) {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.arrItems.removeAll {$0.id == item.id}
                               }
                    } label: {
                        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```